# How can I get a user to specify a Windows drive letter when using cdrecord?

Tags: java, windows

I currently provide a dropdown list from the results of cdrecord -scanbus, to allow the user to select a drive to write data to.  cdrecord -scanbus outputs something like:

```
$ cdrecord -scanbus
Cdrecord-ProDVD-ProBD-Clone 3.00 (i686-pc-cygwin) Copyright (C) 1995-2010 J▒rg Schilling
Using libscg version 'schily-0.9'.
scsibus0:
    0,0,0     0) 'MATSHITA' 'DVD-R   UJ-857D ' 'KCVB' Removable CD-ROM
    0,1,0     1) *
    0,2,0     2) *
    0,3,0     3) *
    0,4,0     4) *
    0,5,0     5) *
    0,6,0     6) *
    0,7,0     7) HOST ADAPTOR
scsibus1:
    1,0,0   100) *
    1,1,0   101) 'ST950032' '5AS             ' '0001' Disk
    1,2,0   102) *
    1,3,0   103) *
    1,4,0   104) *
    1,5,0   105) *
    1,6,0   106) *
    1,7,0   107) HOST ADAPTOR
```

Some users find it hard to work out which of those their drive is, even if I filter out anything that doesn't contain DVD or CD, whereas they tend to know which Windows drive letter their drive is.  How can I convert, in either direction?  I'm doing this from a Java program, but a solution in any language or on the command line might help.